# Android App Failed To Load On Blackberry Z10

Tags: android, eclipse, blackberry, android-logcat

Okay, let me first apologize by saying this is my first post on stackoverflow and haven't been coding that long so this may be a simple error on my part. Also let me thank you ahead of time for trying to help me. So this is basically what is ailing me, I have a app i have coded that is used to set wallpapers on android phones and recently have been submitted to blackberry's appworld.

I have never had any issue with the app until the other day when all of a sudden when i changed the package name to a new one. Note this is of a fresh install of the app. But for some reason the Blackberry Z10 is opening the app for about a second and shows me a black screen for less then a second and then close. However, my eclipse's logcat states otherwise and that it is still loading. Note that I have other apps using the same setup and library as this app and also have recently changed their package names and haven't run into this problem. Also this only happens on Blackberry Phones and doesnt give me this issue on any normal android phones.

Here is my logcat: http://pastebin.com/EzD6eQaU

If you have any idea why this is happening please let me know.

Thank you again,
Dalton

Answer (score 0):

It took a while but i found out what was my issue. Blackberry has a package name character limit of at least 50 characters long. Any more then that and your app wont work on blackberry.